# Das Wort "ich" in offiziellen Schreiben

Tags: word-choice

Sollte man einen Anfang wie z.B. "Ich, `<Name>`, geboren in ..., bestätige dass ..." vermeiden? Gibt es bessere Alternativen statt "ich", die öfter verwendet werden, z.B. "Unterschreiber" oder etwas ähnliches? Interessanterweise beschränken sich die Beispiele die Google liefert auf solche Dinge wie Datum, Adressierung, usw., und zeigen nicht wie man sich selber vorstellen sollte.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ich" am Anfang eines Briefes sollte vermieden werden. Eine typische Formulierung für Deinen Text wäre zum Beispiel:

> Hiermit bestätige ich, *Name,* geboren in …, dass …

Answer (score 4):

"Ich" ist immer korrekt. Bei persönlichen Dingen, etwa bei Kundenkontakt oder wenn man sich selbst anderen vorstellt, dann schreibt man immer "ich". Formen wie "Unterschreiber" oder "Unterzeichner" sind auch korrekt, werden aber viel seltener verwendet, hauptsächlich bei sehr förmlichen, sachlichen, distanzierten Dingen, zum Beispiel bei Rechtsangelegenheiten. Wenn man diese Formen benutzt, spricht man von sich selbst in der dritten Person und drückt damit etwa professionelle Distanz aus. Beispielsweise könnte ein Polizist in seinem Bericht schreiben: "Der Verdächtige machte gegenüber dem Ermittler keine Angabe", oder in einem Gutachten könnte es heißen: "Der Unterzeichner ist der Ansicht, dass es beim Bau erhebliche Mängel gab", oder in einem Vertrag könnte stehen: "Der Unterzeichner bestätigt hiermit, sämtliche Rechte an seinen Werken abzutreten". In diesen Fällen wäre es zu persönlich, wenn man "ich" schreibt.

Comment: „Unterschreiber“ habe ich noch nie gehört, es gibt auch nur wenige Google-Treffer und keine in dieser Verwendung. „Unterzeichner“ kommt vor, häufiger wäre aber „der Unterzeichnete“ (oder „der Unterzeichnende“).

Comment: Recht hast du, Unterschreiber sagt man nicht.

Comment: `Der Unterzeichnete` gibt es auch nicht. Unterzeichnet kann nur der Vertrag sein, aber Personen sind nicht unterzeichnet - allenfalls bei einem eitlen Tätowierer könnte derartiges passieren.

Comment: @userunknown: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Unterzeichneter

Comment: @Mac: Tatsache!

Comment: Allerdings gibt es die Regel, dass man "ich" als *erstes* Wort nach der Anrede vermeiden sollte. Allerdings nicht in dem Sinne, dass man dafür ein anderes Wort nehmen sollte, sondern dass man den Satz nach Möglichkeit entsprechend umstellt. Also z.B. statt "Sehr geehrter Herr Soundso, ich möchte Ihr Angebot ... annehmen." schreiben "Sehr geehrter Herr Sowieso, Ihr Angebot ... möchte ich annehmen."